# 100vh не занимает всю высоту экрана

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка

использую height со значением 100vh, что, как я понимаю, должно растянуть блок на всю высоту экрана, но этого визуально не происходит (хотя в инспекторе показывает, что занимают всю высоту, как видно на фото)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чем может быть дело?

### ps

### заметил, что если удалить все секции ниже, то все становиться нормально

заметил, что если убираю 1 определенную секцию, то все становиться нормально, буду искать в ней причину

Comment: А зачем так устанавливать? Сделайте просто `top: 0; bottom: 0;`

Comment: тоже кстати вариант, спасибо)
просто у куратор, курс которого я смотрю, так  сделал и у него все чики пуки, а у меня вот такая байда.

 НО! я нашел причину. Все из-за 1 изображения, которое выходило за пределы в ширину,  я поставил тому изображению 100% и все стало работать

Answer (score 1):

Не могу оставить комментарий, так что пишу через ответ - вы пытаетесь реализовать всплывающее меню как я понял, но высоту задаете списку, а не родителю списка - скорее всего список ограничен высотой родителя, проверьте. Если добавите код верстки и стилей будет понятней.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Да, всплывающее меню. Я делаю по урокам и куратор сделал так, я даже скопировал его код, но почему-то, в отличии от него, у меня изображение в нижней секции выходило за пределы страницы, в этом и была моя проблема. Я поправил ширину изображения и все стало нормально. курс 2019 года, может что изменилось за это время в css и так случилось, не знаю

Comment: @Skait https://codepen.io/poliweb/pen/JzaMdm - ссылка на удобный для начала бургер-меню на JQuery

Comment: @Skait вы проверили родителя списка? Удалось решить проблему?